# use streaming mode for chunked encoding and sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection writeRequests in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, chunked-encoding

use streaming mode for chunked encoding  and sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection writeRequests in jmeter in NON gui mode iam getting, please help me how to resolve this issues[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zstyt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Implementation" of your HTTP Request sampler to `HttpClient4`, the setting lives at "Advanced" tab:

[image]

If you have more than 1 HTTP Request sampler to amend it makes sense to go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) which provides the "default" values for all HTTP Request samplers in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).